# ReferenceError: PF is not defined

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces

I tried the [NotificationBar](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/notificationBar.jsf) example of PrimeFaces, however it didn't work. I get the following JS error:

> ReferenceError: PF is not defined

I think I need to include a library before using `PF()` function, but I don't know which library and where can I find it.

Comment: can you try *widgetVar.show()*

Comment: It doesn't work too !

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The JS function `PF()` is only available since 4.0. You're apparently using PF 3.x. Look at the footer of the showcase site, it's currently saying that it's running PF 4.0.

Just use `widgetVar.show()`, where `widgetVar` is the widget variable name as you specified in `widgetVar`, which is `bar` in their showcase example.

```
<p:commandButton value="Show" onclick="bar.show()" type="button" />  
<p:commandButton value="Hide" onclick="bar.hide()" type="button" />
```

Comment: I am using primeface 5.2 but not able to access PF(). do I need to include any file in javascript?